# using the variable from a cursor loop in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor

This is what i have and what I want to do is use [Value] in my select.  I'm not sure what exactly to use in the select statement!  Thanks!

```
DECLARE
TCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[SPLIT] (';', @SplitVar);
OPEN TCursor ;
FETCH NEXT FROM TCursor ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @ETo =
         (SELECT Email
            FROM mytable
           WHERE user= TCursor );
  EXEC sp_SendAn
```

i'm not sure about this part `SELECT Email                FROM mytable               WHERE user= TCursor`

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the cursor value into a variable:

```
DECLARE @curvar VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE
TCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[SPLIT] (';', @SplitVar);
OPEN TCursor ;
FETCH NEXT FROM TCursor INTO @curvar;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @ETo =
         (SELECT Email
            FROM mytable
           WHERE user= @curvar );
  EXEC sp_SendAn
```

Not sure what you intend to do with `@Eto`, you may have to use:

```
  SET @ETo = '
         (SELECT Email
            FROM mytable
           WHERE user= '+@curvar+' )'
  EXEC sp_SendAn
```